# How to access form object from wordpress rest api

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using this ajax call params to pass data:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', selectedFile);
formData.append('subject', 'test subject');
formData.append('message', 'test message');

url: 'my/endpoint',
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false
```

Here is my endpoint:

```
function test_endpoint(WP_REST_Request $request){
   return $request->get_body();
   //return wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

I can see the data:

[image]

So basically I am trying to access the form parameters so I can put them into an email. I can't figure our how to access file, subject and message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was my ajax. So I switched to straight XHR and it worked:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'my/endpoint', true);
 xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('response',JSON.parse(this.responseText));
 };
xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't or at least shouldn't call ajax directly when using Wordpress.
There is a mechanism built in to deal with ajax calls.

More or less what you have to do is:

Write the function of what will be executed on the server when the ajax call is triggered and then bind it to an ajax callback action.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'my_ajax_processing_func' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'my_ajax_processing_func' );

function my_ajax_processing_func() {
    <Your processing here>
}
```

note the '*myaction*' part in the `add_action()`. In the form data sent from the client, there has to be an `action` parameter set to this identifief (*myaction*) for the binding to take place.

Also in the form the `url` has to be set to the `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`. The way of getting hold of this url is to download it to the js script using `wp_localized_script()`.

You can find a full explanation here:
[Using AJAX With PHP on Your WordPress Site Without a Plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/)

Also chck out this article to add a nonce to the form for security reasons.
[How to Add a WordPress AJAX Nonce](https://eric.blog/2013/06/18/how-to-add-a-wordpress-ajax-nonce/)

Comment: I'm not using ajax on my WP site. I'm just using the WP Rest API. I've made dozens of other requests no problem. My issue is that I need to pass an image, hence the new FormData (or I would just pass an obj as json). So all I need is to retrieve the values of the FormData.

Comment: I've never used the rest api, but I found this link that seems to be upload a file using the wp rest api. Perhaps it helps you work around your issue. https://gist.github.com/ahmadawais/0ccb8a32ea795ffac4adfae84797c19a